# Тема Cactus WordPress отключить мобильную версию

Tags: html, css, wordpress, мобильная-разработка

Тема Cactus WordPress отключить мобильную версию - сделать, чтобы при загрузке с мобильного отобржалась полная версия.

Comment: Если вы думаете, что в WordPress существует только одна тема, и только один способ создания мобильной версии, то вы глубоко заблуждаетесь. Почитайте о том, как правильно задать вопрос по WordPress https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6688/220220

Comment: шаблон Cactus...

Comment: Чтобы вас понимали, следует применять правильную терминологию. Шаблон в WordPress - это один php-файл, содержащий код вывода страницы, категории и т.п. Ваш Cactus - это тема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте дочернюю тему. Скопируйте в неё файл header.php из темы cactus. В скопированном файле замените строку

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

на

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

В примере 1024 - ширина экрана. Подставьте сюда своё значение.